# HUE integration with Dataproc cluster

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc, hue

Is there anyway to integrate HUE with dataproc cluster?

Comment: did you check [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/hue) ?

Comment: Yeah.. But i need to know is someone already done this part and are they facing any issue?

Comment: Sorry, i have not. but doing experiment is always worth time.

Comment: Well. Use Hue just will work as an interface for data proc. I've already seen this question before. check this link https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/hue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HUE is supported on Dataproc via initialization action, you can find details how to use it in README:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/hue

For example, to create Dataproc cluster with HUE use the command:

```sh
REGION=<region>
CLUSTER_NAME=<cluster_name>
gcloud dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
    --region ${REGION} \
    --initialization-actions gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/hue/hue.sh
```

Comment: If we install Hue in a cluster and clients expect the Hue to be up all times, then we cannot use a preemptible cluster, am I right?

Comment: @Kuwali Master nodes in the Dataproc cluster (where Hue is installed) can not use preemptible VMs. If you mean ephemeral clusters (create only when necessary) then yes, probably you can not use them out of the box and need to add automation to create cluster when necessary. Alternatively you can create a single-node persistent cluster that runs Hue and connects to ephemeral clusters that are created on-demand - this way clients will be able connect to Hue always.

Comment: Thanks  a lot @Igor for your answer. Yes, I meant ephemeral cluster.